# I am getting weird voltages on three phase to ground. What's wrong?

Tags: voltage, three-phase

I had to measure our three-phase service for configuration of new equipment. This is in Indiana. Line to line reads about 246 V, but line to ground is 1.4 V on line A, 42 V from line B, and 44 V from line C.

This is measured with a 5 kW AM transmitter as a load. This makes no sense to me; can anyone explain?

I could not measure with no load as we could not take the station off the air.

Comment: Are you certain that you measure against a valid ground?

Answer (score 6):

It's probably an ungrounded delta service, with some resistive or capacitive leakage to ground. If you connect a lamp or other small load from the phase you are measuring to GND, each will probably read close to zero. And if you add loads from each phase to GND, or to a common point, it will establish a virtual neutral, and your voltages should read the expected 142 VAC.

[3 Phase Delta with Ground Reference?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/323650/3-phase-delta-with-ground-reference)

[image: Image from above link showing creation of virtual neutral]

https://spinningnumbers.org/a/delta-wye-resistor-networks.html

The proper way to create a true Wye service from a Delta is to use a three phase transformer.

Comment: It's probably worth checking that the floating neutral is intentional though, especially if this is part of the process of diagnosing a fault.